# TCL error with "unfold" function in survival analysis

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit, unfold

I am trying to use the `unfold` function from package `RcmdrPlugin.survival`.
I used the following command:

```
long.df <- unfold(testdf,time="deathint", event="death",
                  cov=list(31:70,71:110), cov.names=c("adopted","age"))
```

However, R is returning the following error message:

> Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTcl, ...), class = "tclObj") : 
>     [tcl] wrong # args: should be "winfo rootx window".

I am using R version 3.2.4. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in an R package. The `winfo rootx` command only ever takes one argument, and hasn't changed in _decades._

Comment: I would think this to be an @JohnFox question/bug report. You ought to make a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. This wouldn't be an issue - I can use alternatives to `unfold` - only I'm trying to reproduce someone else's results using their code. I know the command worked for them when they wrote the code, so the package must have compatibility issues with more recent versions of R.

Comment: May I ask what alternative you used?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in R studio. This is how I solved it:
intall.packages("Rcmdr")
It installed R commander gui for me,then I went to R commander gui, installed and loaded RcdmrPlugin.survival and then I ran unfold from there and it worked.

Comment: However, after unfolding, all of the event.time values are zero, no matter if the event happened or not!