# NAs by coercion when using unfold() in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'm trying to replicate "Cox proportional-Hazard Regression..." and to use the unfold function, I get the following warning "Warning in lapply(data, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion".
The first time I tried it, I had no issues but it hasn't worked since. I'm running this script in MacBook M2 but getting Rossi.2 as a 0 obs. of 14 variables dataframe.

```
url <- "http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/data/Rossi.txt"
Rossi <- read.table(url, header = TRUE)
library(survival)
library(RcmdrPlugin.survival)
Rossi.2 <- unfold(Rossi, time= "week",
                  event="arrest", cov=11:62, cov.names="employed")
```

I have reinstalled and upgraded XQuartz and the RcmdrPlugin.survival package, I have restarted R multiple times. All the times I still get the warning for all observations and get the same 0 observation dataframe as a result. On the paper the result is an unfolded dataframe and then run a Cox regression but that's clearly not possible without observations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TCL error with "unfold" function in survival analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401841/tcl-error-with-unfold-function-in-survival-analysis)

Comment: @asd-tm I tried it, the Rcommander launches without issues but I still get 0 observations in Rossi.2

Comment: I guess it is a bug in the library. The sample from ducumentation `?unfold()` causes an error